# переопределение шаблона в angular2

Tags: наследование, typescript, angular2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переопределить шаблон angular2. Есть модуль селектбокса ng2-select. В этом модуле надо изменить шаблон: добавить кастомный scrollbar (ng2-slimscroll), немного изменить вёрстку. Вопрос состоит в том, как это реализовать в angular2? 
сейчас компонента выглядит так:

```
import {  Component } from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass} from '@angular/common';

import {BUTTON_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import {SELECT_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-select/ng2-select';

import {BaseComponent} from '../base/base.component';


@Component({
selector: 'content',
templateUrl: 'app/admin/generation/generation.component.html',
directives: [SELECT_DIRECTIVES],
styleUrls: ['../../node_modules/ng2-select/components/css/ng2-select.css']
})

export class GenerationComponent  {

public items:Array<string> = ['Amsterdam', 'Antwerp', 'Athens', 'Barcelona',
    'Berlin', 'Birmingham', 'Bradford', 'Bremen', 'Brussels', 'Bucharest',
    'Budapest', 'Cologne', 'Copenhagen', 'Dortmund', 'Dresden', 'Dublin',
    'Düsseldorf', 'Essen', 'Frankfurt', 'Genoa', 'Glasgow', 'Gothenburg',
    'Hamburg', 'Hannover', 'Helsinki', 'Kraków', 'Leeds', 'Leipzig', 'Lisbon',
    'London', 'Madrid', 'Manchester', 'Marseille', 'Milan', 'Munich', 'Málaga',
    'Naples', 'Palermo', 'Paris', 'Poznań', 'Prague', 'Riga', 'Rome',
    'Rotterdam', 'Seville', 'Sheffield', 'Sofia', 'Stockholm', 'Stuttgart',
    'The Hague', 'Turin', 'Valencia', 'Vienna', 'Vilnius', 'Warsaw', 'Wrocław',
    'Zagreb', 'Zaragoza', 'Łódź'];

private value:any = {};
private _disabledV:string = '0';
private disabled:boolean = false;

private get disabledV():string {
    return this._disabledV;
}

private set disabledV(value:string) {
    this._disabledV = value;
    this.disabled = this._disabledV === '1';
}

public selected(value:any):void {
    console.log('Selected value is: ', value);
}

public removed(value:any):void {
    console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
}

public typed(value:any):void {
    console.log('New search input: ', value);
}

public refreshValue(value:any):void {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартно такое не поддерживается, но есть декораторы которые позволяют переопределить часть полей родительского декоратора:

> @WjComponent decorator
>
> The answer: the @WjComponent decorator offered by the Wijmo for
>   Angular 2 module. It’s used in the same way as the standard @Component
>   decorator and accepts all @Component decorator’s properties (plus some
>   that are Wijmo-specific), but its main benefit is that it merges its
>   property values with the properties provided by the base class
>   decorator

http://wijmo.com/blog/using-class-inheritance-to-create-a-custom-component-in-angular-2/